# ¿Como se que botón del ratón presione en un elemento canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5

De la siguiente manera no me obtiene el clic derecho, sino que saca el menú de opciones que tienen los elementos canvas, ¿como podría eliminar ese menú y obtener el evento?

```js
function dibujaForma(){
    // Toma el elemento canvas usando el DOM
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

    // Asegurate de no ejecutar el canvas en navegadores que no lo soporten
    if (canvas.getContext){
       // usa getContext para empezar al dibujar en el canvas
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

       // Dibuja Lineas
       for (i=0;i<10;i++){
         ctx.lineWidth = 1+i;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(5+i*14,5);
         ctx.lineTo(5+i*14,140);
         ctx.stroke();
      }
   } else {
         alert('Necesitas Safari o Firefox 1.5+ para ver esta demo.');
   }
   
   

        document.getElementById("mycanvas").onclick = function(evt){   
           if (event.button==2){
              console.log('presiono clic derecho');
            }else{
              console.log('presiono clic izquierdo');
            }
        }
   
   
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<body id="test" onload="dibujaForma();">
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el evento `contextmenu` registrandolo con `addEventListener` y cuando obtengas el evento, utiliza el metodo preventDefault() para que no aparezca el menu por defecto que aparece con el clic derecho:

```js
function dibujaForma(){
    // Toma el elemento canvas usando el DOM
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

    // Asegurate de no ejecutar el canvas en navegadores que no lo soporten
    if (canvas.getContext){
       // usa getContext para empezar al dibujar en el canvas
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

       // Dibuja Lineas
       for (i=0;i<10;i++){
         ctx.lineWidth = 1+i;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(5+i*14,5);
         ctx.lineTo(5+i*14,140);
         ctx.stroke();
      }
   } else {
         alert('Necesitas Safari o Firefox 1.5+ para ver esta demo.');
   }
   
   

    document.getElementById("mycanvas").onclick = function(evt){   
        if (event.button==2){
          console.log('presiono clic derecho');
        }else{
          console.log('presiono clic izquierdo');
        }
    }
    
     document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener('contextmenu', function(evt){   
           evt.preventDefault(); // remueve esta linea si quieres que aparezca el menu por defecto.
           console.log("preciono clic derecho");
        },false);
   
   
   
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<body id="test" onload="dibujaForma();">
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: gracias hermano, no lo conseguía por ningún lado.

Comment: Siempre. Recuerda marcarla si esta es la respuesta que esperabas.

Comment: Creí q ya le había dado, disculpa.